# In Angular 9, how to only use cache for an http get request if navigator is not online

Tags: angular

I have a Angular 9 app which makes http.get calls to an API.  I have implemented angular-pwa to allow offline functionnalities.

What i have a hard time figuring out is when the browser is online, I do not want to use the cached response for 2 given requests.

I tried setting up my ngsw-config.json

...

```
"dataGroups": [
        {
            "name": "api-performance",
            "urls": [
                "**/assets/**",
                "**/api/**",
                "**/materialicons/**"
            ],
            "cacheConfig": {
                "strategy": "performance",
                "maxAge": "12h",
                "maxSize": 200,
                "timeout": "50s"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "api-freshness",
            "urls": ["**/api/always-get-fresh**", "**/api/always-get-fresh2**"],
            "cacheConfig": {
                "strategy": "freshness",
                "maxAge": "12h",
                "maxSize": 200,
                "timeout": "50s"
            }
        }
    ]
```

....
to use freshness strategy for the 2 specific http get i want fresh and i specified the rest to be performance.

I also tried to delete the caches when the navigator goes back online

in app.component.ts

```
addEventListener('online', (e) => {
            caches.keys().then((cacheNames) => {
                return Promise.all(
                    cacheNames
                        .filter((cacheName) => {
                          return true;
                        })
                        .map((cacheName) => {
                            if (cacheName.search('api-freshness') !== -1) {
                                return caches.delete(cacheName);
                            }
                            return false;
                        })
                );
            });


        });
```

Neither tries have been successful so far.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was the order of the dataGroups.

I put performance after freshness and the 2 http gets are always calling the server unless offline.

the delete cache part was useless and i removed it.